# Add targets dependent on ALL targets

Tags: c, cmake, build-system

I want to build same targets using different compilation flags.
The idea was to add two overriding targets, set corresponding properties on them and add dependency on ALL.
The goal is to build the project with different defines enabling/disabling certain features. The list of output files should remain same.

```
add_custom_target(feature1 COMMENT "Build including feature 1")
set_target_properties(feature1 
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS " -DFEATURE1=1 -DFEATURE2=0 ")
add_dependencies(feature1 ALL)

add_custom_target(feature2 COMMENT "Build including feature 2")
set_target_properties(feature2 
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS " -DFEATURE1=0 -DFEATURE2=1 ")
add_dependencies(feature2 ALL)
```

I get an error:
The dependency target "ALL" of target "feature1" does not exist.

How can I solve that? Or implement in another way?

Comment: `ALL` isn't a keyword in [`add_dependencies`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) afaik.

Comment: Every `add_executable` defines an executable build with a **single set** of compile/link flags. If you want to create **two executables** built from the same source files but with different compile flags, then you need to call `add_executable` **twice** (or more times).

Comment: Preferrably use `target_compile_definitions(feature1 PRIVATE FEATURE1=1 FEATURE2=0)`. This doesn't solve your issue though. Also not sure why you're trying to set compile flags on a custom target; custom targets require you to specify the command yourself and don't care for the `COMPILE_FLAGS` target property.

Answer (score 0):

`add_dependencies` does not accept `ALL` as a target. You have to specify each target you want to depend upon:

```
# Target "depends" depends upon "first_dependency" and "second_dependency"
add_dependencies(depends first_dependency second_dependency)
```

If you already have a target that you want to build with different options the standard method is to run the configuration step again. However, if you don't want to do this one solution is to add multiple targets with different options. You don't need to add any target dependencies for this. For example:

```
# Set the source files we want to build.
set(MY_SOURCES src1.c src2.c etc)

# Add all the targets we need
add_executable(first_target ${MY_SOURCES})
add_executable(second_target ${MY_SOURCES})

# Add the compile options for each target
target_compile_options(first_target PRIVATE option1 option2 etc)
target_compile_options(second_target PRIVATE option3 option4 etc)
```

Now after running the configuration step once you should have one target for each set of compilation options you need.

Note that I never seen this done. It looks like something you can do, but in practice it may end up in a real mess.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Splitting it to two separate targets indeed is quite messy in my case.
That's why I decided just to reconfigure the project whenever needed with these targets:

```
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(feature1 
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}  --regenerate-during-build -DFEATURE1=1 -DFEATURE2=0 -S${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -B${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  COMMENT "Switch to Feature 1"
  )
ADD_CUSTOM_TARGET(feature2
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}  --regenerate-during-build -DFEATURE1=0 -DFEATURE2=1 -S${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} -B${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  COMMENT "Switch to Feature 2"
  )
```

And then I just build all.